# How to compare strings by specific SortVersion in C# on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, cultureinfo

I porting an app from **Windows** *.NET Framework* to **Linux** *.NET Core*.

We have a `List<string>.Sort()`, and we need to keep it consistent in Linux.

After some research I see that of course, using `List<string>.Sort(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` keeps the same results in **Windows**, but in **Linux**, the value of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Version` is different, so I can't sort as the same way.

(I tried to sort by `OrdinalIgnoreCase` but it changes the original sort in **Windows**)

So how can I sort strings with specific [`SortVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareinfo.version)?

Comment: You should probably supply some data and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The C locales probably would not hurt, either.

Comment: There is a lot of test cases, each one failed in a different case. I will add them ASAP.